# AfterBuild contains an IF statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, deployment

Please see the following afterbuild command (BuildEvents\PostBuildEventCommandLine):

```
   if "Release" ==" $(ConfigurationName)" (
       call C:\Users\3212627\Documents\trunk\Genie2\AssignStrongNameSerializer.bat 
     )
```

If I remove the IF statement then the batch script runs after build.  However, if I include it then it does not.  I have definitely selected release build rather than debug build in configuration manager.  What is wrong with the IF statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra leading space in your string:

```
" $(ConfigurationName)"
```

but you should use

```
"$(ConfigurationName)"
```

since `"Release" <> " Release"`

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to build events.  That was the answer.  I wish I didn't ask the question now.  I would of deleted it but you answered to quickily.